# Numerics on 2D XY Model Critical Exponents

Tags: statistical-mechanics

I was wondering if there are any references on the critical exponents of the 2D XY model, and in particular, the value of $\eta$ in the correlations function $\langle \sigma_0 \cdot \sigma_r \rangle$ at $T_c$ (defined by the BKT transition).

The usual argument is via (non-rigorous) RG analysis which gives the answer $\eta =1/4$, but I haven't been able to find any numerics on this (one would think Wikipedia would be a sufficient source due to how the old the topic is).
I'm interested mostly because I'm curious on how good of a approximation is this. Indeed, since the 2D Ising model is exactly solvable and gives $\eta =1/4$, it's quite interesting/odd to see that the 2D XY and 2D Ising have the same correlation decay at criticality.

Comment: A quick search on Google Scholar for "XY Model Monte Carlo" reveals many potentially useful references.

Answer (score 0):

I have followed the comment by Zack and found some useful references:

- [Martin Hasenbusch, "The two-dimensional XY model at the transition
  temperature: a high-precision Monte Carlo study"](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0305-4470/38/26/003/meta?casa_token=nJcmakgf1ksAAAAA:aLVkQlOVIACBCBrmBhjvKjziGz1vgc1jUzWAyf1KMYcWFAgp9PRSP-J_4q0wgev1sGLhLm9PbHZlje0QO1R1lxOee7BV) - In this reference the authors calculate the observable that you were interested in, as well as the $\eta$ and the leading correction to the finite size scaling.
- [Yukihiro Komura and Yutaka Okabe, "Large-Scale Monte Carlo Simulation of Two-Dimensional Classical XY Model Using Multiple GPUs"](https://journals.jps.jp/doi/10.1143/JPSJ.81.113001) - I have just skimmed through the paper but it seems that it also discusses similar issues as the first one.

Both of these references are also mentioned in the context of the XY model in the review by Kosterlitz himself ([J Michael Kosterlitz, "Kosterlitz–Thouless physics: a review of key issues"](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0034-4885/79/2/026001/meta?casa_token=mWiL3qhEgSMAAAAA:uPE_E16Mei4LZQdWMnFZLiMn69ipFd301VsJYwwLdy008fBMN9M2UM2cPMbCBbY_eSlbqhwAgfDbg1P9KhBCcrIzEKRx)).

Comment: I have also only skimmed through the two papers, so maybe I'm missing something, but in both case, it seems that they only quote $\eta=1/4$ and their main result is the logarithmic corrections. Their quote of $\eta=1/4$, as far as I can tell, comes from the RG analysis done by Kosterlitz, which is not exact